# WC REST API | HTML Table does not get created

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

The WC Rest API updloads the product to the wordpress site. All the entires are correctly uploaded, however under short discription, the table does not get created, only the plane text of the table is displayed in non table format, just in straight line in woocommerce-api.php.

Code:

```
print_r( $client->products->create( array( 'title' => 'Nile - Over Counter Basin','sku' => '91081_Nile', 'type' => 'simple', 'regular_price' => '7260', 'sale_price' => '5445','description' => 'Nile - Over Counter BasinOver Counter BasinHindware Italian CollectionContemporary design with smooth flowing line Space for toiletries', 'dimensions'=>array( 'length' =>'67.5' ,'width' =>'39.5','height'=>'12.5'), 'categories'=>array( ' SANITARYWARE' =>'592',' WASHBASIN' =>'650',' Table Top Wash Basin' =>'508'),'images' =>Array ('91081_Nile'=>Array('src'=>'http://www.somethingsomething.com/images/products/91081/2.jpg','title'=>'91081_Nile','position'=>'0') ),'short_description'=>'Contemporary design with smooth flowing line Space for toiletries <table id="ProductDescriptiontable"><tr><td>Brand</td><td>:</td><td class="thirdcolumn">Hindware</td></tr><tr><td>Product Name</td><td>:</td><td class="thirdcolumn">Nile - Over Counter Basin</td></tr><tr><td>Product Description</td><td>:</td><td class="thirdcolumn">Table Top Wash Basin</td></tr></tr><tr><td>Product Color</td><td>:</td><td class="thirdcolumn">StarwhiteIvory</td></tr></table>')  ) ) ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer lies in `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/api/class-wc-api-product.php` on line #244

```
// Enable short description html tags.
$post_excerpt = isset( $data['short_description'] ) ? wc_clean( $data['short_description'] ) : '';
if ( $post_excerpt && isset( $data['enable_html_short_description'] ) && true === $data['enable_html_short_description'] ) {
    $post_excerpt = $data['short_description'];
}
```

That piece of code in the first line cleans the short description using `wc_clean`, it then check to see if `enable_html_short_description` key was passed in the data and if that was set to `true`, when the condition is met it will pass the "non-clean" version of short description as was received.

A slight change to your code above will get you the desired result

```
print_r( $client->products->create( array( 
    'title' => 'Nile - Over Counter Basin',
    'sku' => '91081_Nile', 
    'type' => 'simple', 
    'regular_price' => '7260',
    'sale_price' => '5445',
    'description' => 'Nile - Over Counter BasinOver Counter BasinHindware Italian CollectionContemporary design with smooth flowing line Space for toiletries', 
    'dimensions'=>array( 'length' =>'67.5' ,'width' =>'39.5','height'=>'12.5'), 
    'categories'=>array( ' SANITARYWARE' =>'592',' WASHBASIN' =>'650',' Table Top Wash Basin' =>'508'),
    'images' =>Array ('91081_Nile'=>Array('src'=>'http://www.somethingsomething.com/images/products/91081/2.jpg','title'=>'91081_Nile','position'=>'0') ),
    'short_description'=>'Contemporary design with smooth flowing line Space for toiletries <table id="ProductDescriptiontable"><tr><td>Brand</td><td>:</td><td class="thirdcolumn">Hindware</td></tr><tr><td>Product Name</td><td>:</td><td class="thirdcolumn">Nile - Over Counter Basin</td></tr><tr><td>Product Description</td><td>:</td><td class="thirdcolumn">Table Top Wash Basin</td></tr></tr><tr><td>Product Color</td><td>:</td><td class="thirdcolumn">StarwhiteIvory</td></tr></table>',
    'enable_html_short_description' => true,  // This is the line you need to add 
)  ) ) ;
```

Comment: i am using https://github.com/kloon/WooCommerce-REST-API-Client-Library. and i do not have a folder includes/api/class-wc-api-product.php

Comment: I have tested using the same API library and it works. The file I mentioned is a WooCoommerce core file, look in `plugins/woocommerce/includes/api/` . I am using the latest version of WooCommerce 2.4.6

Comment: I really dont know how to thank you.. i have been working on this for hours and finally you came like a angel and fixed it.. perfect.. working good.. thank you a million.. I need your guidance in the different topic of same api.. can i ask ?

Comment: The community here at SO is very helpful, if its not me it will be someone else who will help you. :) Just post your question but show some evidence to the community that you tried something and are stuck. And yes I am glad I could help.

Comment: thank you, i have asked the question in the url: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32414186/wc-rest-api-attributes-not-uploading, this is my main issue i am stuck here for 2 days now.. attributes are not getting uploaded in the product..