# WC REST API | Attributes not uploading

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a Attribute called "Color" and it has two attributes "Red" and "Green".
When i run this using WC REST API

Everything is working from the below code, i am stuck with the attributes.

```
print_r( $client->products->create( array( 
    'title' => 'Nile - Over Counter Basin',
    'sku' => '91081_Nile', 
    'type' => 'simple', 
    'regular_price' => '7260',
    'sale_price' => '5445',
    'description' => 'Nile - Over Counter BasinOver Counter BasinHindware Italian CollectionContemporary design with smooth flowing line Space for toiletries', 
    'dimensions'=>array( 'length' =>'67.5' ,'width' =>'39.5','height'=>'12.5'), 
    'categories'=>array( ' SANITARYWARE' =>'592',' WASHBASIN' =>'650',' Table Top Wash Basin' =>'508'),
    'images' =>Array ('91081_Nile'=>Array('src'=>'http://www.somethingsomething.com/images/products/91081/2.jpg','title'=>'91081_Nile','position'=>'0') ),
    'short_description'=>'Contemporary design with smooth flowing line Space for toiletries <table id="ProductDescriptiontable"><tr><td>Brand</td><td>:</td><td class="thirdcolumn">Hindware</td></tr><tr><td>Product Name</td><td>:</td><td class="thirdcolumn">Nile - Over Counter Basin</td></tr><tr><td>Product Description</td><td>:</td><td class="thirdcolumn">Table Top Wash Basin</td></tr></tr><tr><td>Product Color</td><td>:</td><td class="thirdcolumn">StarwhiteIvory</td></tr></table>',
'attributes' => Array ('name'=>'Color','slug'=>'color','position'=>'0','visible'=>'true','options'=>'Red'),
    'enable_html_short_description' => true,  // This is the line you need to add 
)  ) ) ;
```

**Anand:** After adding the attributes in multiple array, the attributes are displayed in correct section, but they are not considered as attributes, .. please see the image, they are seen as a plain text and not as an attributes.
**My Code is:**

```
'attributes'=>array(array('name'=>'Color','Slug'=>'color','position'=>'0','visible'=>true,'options'=>'Starwhite'),array('name'=>'Model',
'Slug'=>'model','position'=>'0','visible'=>true,'options'=>'Pedestal Wash Basin'),array('name'=>'Brands','Slug'=>'brands','position'=>'0','visible'=>true,'options'=>'Hindware'),array('name'=>'Washbasin Size','Slug'=>'washbasin-size','position'=>'0','visible'=>true,'options'=>'56 x 46 x 38.5 cm'),array('name'=>'Washbasin Type','Slug'=>'washbasin-type','position'=>'0','visible'=>true,'options'=>'Washbasin With Pedestal'))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass attributes as an array of arrays, change

```
'attributes' => Array ('name'=>'Color','slug'=>'color','position'=>'0','visible'=>'true','options'=>'Red'),
```

to

```
'attributes' => array( array( 'name'=>'Color','slug'=>'color','position'=>'0','visible'=>'true','options'=>'Red' ) ),
```

P.S: I am presuming there that the taxonomy and term already exist, and that the taxonomy's type is set to text.

**EDIT**

When the taxonomy's type is set to "text" pass `options` as plain text

```
'options' => 'term'
```

When the taxonomy's type is set to "select" pass `options` as an array

```
'options' => array( 'red', 'white' )
```

To pass multiple attributes, send them as an array of arrays, for eg:

```
'attributes'=>array(
    array( 'name'=>'Color', 'slug'=>'color', 'position'=>'0', 'visib‌​le'=>true, 'options'=> array('Starwhite') ),
    array( 'name'=>'Washbasin Type', 'slug'=>'washbasin-type', 'position'=>'0', 'visible'=>true, 'options'=> array(‌​'Washbasin With Pedestal') ),
);
```

Comment: Again, thank you a million, this worked. Many people suggested to change the API version.. but this solved my issue..

Comment: how will i modify your solution if i have multiple attributes for the same products, will they come under multiple Array ? or single Arrary ? can you share an example for the below please ? Multiple Attributes:  (Color : White, Red)
(Model: Wall Mounted)
(Tank: Ceramic)

Comment: You need to pass multiple array elements, for eg `'attributes' => array(  array('name'=>'color'....), array( 'name' => 'model'.....) )`

Comment: the attributes are taken as plain text, and not like the real attributes. example i have attached the image in the question above. The Pedestal wash basin is shown as plain text, but it should be shown as the real attribute like seen for Table Top wash basin.. can you suggest, if i am dong anything wrong..

Comment: When the taxonomy's type is set to "Select" , you need to pass the options as an array, `'options'=>array('Red')`

Comment: thank you for replying, i tried this and i think it did not work.. 'attributes'=>array(array('name'=>'Color','Slug'=>'color','position'=>'0','visible'=>true,'options'=>array('Starwhite')),array('name'=>'Washbasin Type','Slug'=>'washbasin-type','position'=>'0','visible'=>true,'options'=>array('Washbasin With Pedestal'))))  ) ) ;

Comment: how do i check, what is the type of taxonomy, is there a specific file where i can see this option that is choosen ?

Comment: There are a lot of brackets in your code which aren't required. I have updated my answer. Also please don't capitalize the keys , it should be `slug` and not `Slug` . To check the Taxonomy's type, navigate to Products -> Attributes , look at the 3rd column on that page.

Comment: I tried again and it worked this time.. Also is it the same way to upload information for SEO section of each product ? Or shuld i use a different api for seo by yoast

Comment: I am not familiar with that plugin and don't know if  it does have an API, so unfortunately I'll not be able to help on that.